# Querying Advanced Custom Fields; want to paginate the results

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, advanced-custom-fields

Not sure if this pertains specifically to Advanced Custom Fields, but I'll keep this short. I'm relatively new to PHP and want to know the best way of approaching this task. **Also, this is a WordPress (4.1.1) environment**.

I'm sending a query for all post types with an associated category type to pull in and display.  If the query can find posts, it produces an <article> block with additional html for each result.  Not to complicated right?

Now, I want to create a pagination element if/when the query produces greater than 8 results.

Environment with the front-end of the query results can be found: 
http://test-hdwg.pantheon.io/news/

Template being utilized for this page (news.php) contains the following:

```
<?php /* Template Name: News */ ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

        <main id="primary" class="content-area">
          <div class="jumbotron">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="intro">
                <p><?php the_field('news_heading') ?></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="news">
            <div class="row news-articles">
              <div class="column-wrapper">
                <div class="small-4 columns news-left-column">
                  <div class="select-dropdown">
                    <button href="#" data-dropdown="dropdown-items" aria-controls="dropdown-items" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown">Select a news category</button>
                    <ul id="dropdown-items" data-dropdown-content class="f-dropdown" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">
                      <?php $args = array(
                        'exclude'            => '',
                        'title_li'           => __( '' ),
                        'show_option_none'   => __( '<li><a href="#primary">No categories</a></li>' ),
                        'taxonomy'           => 'category',
                        'child_of'           => 2,
                        'current_category'   => 0
                      ); ?>
                      <?php wp_list_categories($args); ?>
                      <li class="cat-item cat-item-all-news"><a href="/news" alt="View all News" title="View all News">All News</a>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="news-block">
                    <span class="news-block-heading">Email Newsletters</span>
                    <div class="news-inner-block">
<?php if( have_rows('newsletters_list') ): ?>
  <?php while( have_rows('newsletters_list') ): the_row(); ?>
                      <span class="year"><?php the_sub_field('newsletter_year'); ?></span>
    <?php if( have_rows('newsletter_resource') ): ?>
                      <ul>
      <?php while( have_rows('newsletter_resource') ): the_row(); ?>
                        <li><a href="<?php the_sub_field('newsletter_url'); ?>" target="_blank"><?php the_sub_field('newsletter_title'); ?></a></li>
      <?php endwhile; ?>
                      </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="small-8 columns news-right-column">
<?php query_posts( 'post_type=post&cat=' ); ?>

  <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                  <article class="large-6 columns ui-article-block">
                    <h3><?php echo get_the_date( 'd M Y' ); ?></h3>
                    <hr/>
                    <h2><?php foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { echo $category->cat_name . ' '; } ?></h2>
                    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                    <p>
      <?php
        $content = get_the_content();
        $content = strip_tags($content);
        echo substr($content, 0, 175) . "..."; // set a character cut-off at 175 characters
      ?>
                    </p>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" alt="Read more about the article: <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" title="Read more about the article: <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" class="button postfix">Read More</a>
                  </article>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
  <?php else : ?>
                  <div class="large-8 columns">
                    <p class="lead">Well this is embarrassing. There are currently no news articles.</p>
                  </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </main>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Just to be clear, this is not an issue, but more-so a request from more experience developers on how to approach a task utilizing Advanced Custom Field elements (if that matters).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

This edit is after clarification from OP on nature of the question.

[The tutorial here](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-numeric-pagination-in-your-wordpress-theme/), explains how to handle numeric navigation in posts at a beginner level.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  That seemed to truncate my results, but I still would like to know if anyone have a recommendation in building the pagination?  We'll need it to display numerical instead of the standard (Previous Posts / Next Posts) WordPress default pagination.

Any recommendations?

Comment: I've added a good resource, also hopefully someone else will chip in as well.

Comment: Thanks for linking me to that resource Jude.  I was able to build the pagination, but I noticed two bugs.  Should I update this post with the bugs I discovered, or, should I create a new question?

Comment: A new question is best .. I'll take a look there

Comment: I've created a new question pertaining to the discoveries I made using the out-of-box approach in the link you suggested.  Please check the question out here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29420662/numerical-pagination-behaving-poorly-in-wordpress when you have a moment, thanks!